# Value in array index does not correspond to another array's index

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with my code and it seems that this portion seems to be causing it.

```
public static boolean[] determine(double avgMilesFlown, double[] numMilesFlown, boolean[] bonusEligibility) {  
      boolean result = false;    
      for (double d : numMilesFlown) {
         if (d > avgMilesFlown) {  

            result = true;
         }

      }  
      bonusEligibility = Arrays.copyOf(bonusEligibility, bonusEligibility.length + 1);
      bonusEligibility[bonusEligibility.length - 1] = result;    
      return bonusEligibility;
   }
```

This block of code is supposed to determine if someone earns a bonus. If their number of miles flown is more than the average miles flown across all entered (including themselves) then they are eligible. My question is am I comparing each individual number of miles flown to the average of miles flown correctly, so that if the number of miles flown is greater than the average, then it will return a list of true's that correspond to each individual.

Normal for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numMilesFlown.length; i++) {
    if (numMilesFlown[i] > avgMilesFlown) {  
        result = true;
    }    
}
```

Example input/output:

```
Names: [tim, jim]
Years Flown: [2, 2]
Miles flown: [45, 43]
Avg Miles: 44
Bonus: [515.00, 515.00]
```

Only Tim should get a bonus because his miles flown is greater than the average, but Jim earns one too, even though his miles flown is below the average.

Comment: *am I comparing each individual number of miles flown to the average of miles flown correctly*? What did the JVM say?

Comment: you may add a `break` statement after `result=true`; as apart of enhancement.

Comment: Use the normal [for](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop instead of the [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)

Comment: It didn't find any errors, but people that shouldn't be earning a bonus, do in the output

Comment: Provide example of input data, expected result, and actual result.

Comment: why are you resizing bonusEligibility? Could you show the invocation code for this method?

Answer (score 1):

`result` can only hold one value at once, so once it is set to true in the for loop, it will remain true the through the entire method and cause everything in `bonusEligibility[]` to also be set to true.

Instead you directly fill `bonusEligibility[]` with corresponding values for `avgMilesFlown[]`. For example:

```
Arrays.fill(bonusEligibility, false);

for (int i = 0; i < numMilesFlown.length; i++) {
    if (numMilesFlown[i] > avgMilesFlown) {  
        bonusEligibility[i] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I see where you're getting at..instead of making a new array, could I just use bonusEligibility[]?

Comment: Good point, that will save the extra step of duplicating an array.